# Matar App al presionar boton atrás

Tags: android

necesito si me pueden ayudar en lo siguiente:

Poseo una app que al comenzar me lanza una splashscreen, luego viene un método de validación (en otra activity) de la conectividad a internet si este es negativo me lanza otra activity señalando que no posee conectividad con un imageview (se carga un SVG o PNG según version S.O), ¿cómo puedo hacer para que al presionar el boton atrás del teléfono termine la app?, probé dentro de onBackPressed con finish(); pero me regresa al activity anterior, también probé con onDestroy pero no hace nada.

Esta es mi Activity:

```
public class SinConexion extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sinconexion);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);// evita que se gire la pantalla

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_sin_conexion);//imageview de splash
            SVG homeSvg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.nosignal);

            imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(homeSvg.createPictureDrawable());

        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.sinconexion);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       super.finish();
        }
}
```

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: ve mi respuesta, el segundo método que es el adecuado para tí, me comentas que sucede :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Elensasys, ahora si está ok.

Comment: Excelente Rodrigo! saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Para cerrar una aplicación a ejecutar el botón "back",

se realiza simplemente ejecutando el método `finish()` a travez de `onKeyDown()`, detectando el evento "Back":

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        super.finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

#### Si deseas cerrar la aplicación desde otra actividad,

puedes implementar este método usando `startActivityForResult()` en la Actividad que abre tu nueva actividad:

```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NuevaActivity.class);            
   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

también agregas el método onActivityResult() en la actividad que abre las actividades:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == 0) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

para terminar la actividad principal.

Comment: Gracias Elenasys, probé con la seguna opción y regresa al activity en donde muestro la imagen de no conectividad, y el super.finish(); me regresa a la activity anterior.

Comment: Esto me parece super extraño, en verdad debería terminar la applicacion! podrías poner tu activity por favor, extiende de que clase?

Comment: Elenasys, agregué una respuesta con el código del activity

Comment: muchas gracias Rodrigo, borra la respuesta, ya he agregado el código a tu pregunta pero que lo podamos revisar!

Comment: Ufff disculpa lo olvidé, gracias

Answer (score 0):

El único método que a mi me ha funcionado, y de verdad quita la app de aplicaciones recientes:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    finishAndRemoveTask();
```

La lástima que es sólo a partir de la api 21