# realizar acción al cerrar app

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría llamar a un método que guarde datos de la sesión cada vez que se cierre la app. He probado con `OnBackpressed()` y `OnDestroy()` pero no me hanfuncionado. ¿Qué método puedo usar para ello?

Answer (score 2):

Al cerrar tu aplicación, cierras la Activity y es llamado el método onDestroy () antes del cierre de la Activity.

Revisa el ciclo de vida de la Activity:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto implementar el método y llamar otro método dentro del mismo:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    // llama método.

}
```

Revisa estas respuestas:

[Evento previo al cierre de aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42549/evento-previo-al-cierre-de-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android)

[Matar App al presionar boton atrás](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8221/matar-app-al-presionar-boton-atr%C3%A1s/8222#8222)

Answer (score 0):

Con esto sobrescribes el método que se ejecuta al pulsar una tecla del móvil, en este caso se comprueba que es la tecla de ir hacia atrás, si estás en la primera actividad de tu aplicación servirá para salir.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
    //Aquí haces lo que te haga falta
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Recuerda que si haces esto, tendrás que escribir un finish(); para cerrar la actividad después de haber hecho lo que tengas que hacer, en este caso guardar los datos que te hagan falta.

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que su aplicación está a punto de obtener "cerrado" va a llamar a algunos métodos en el ciclo de vida de la actividad.

Cuando su actividad recibe una llamada al método onStop(), ya no es visible y debería liberar casi todos los recursos que no son necesarios mientras el usuario no lo está utilizando. Una vez que se detiene su actividad, el sistema podría destruir la instancia si necesita recuperar la memoria del sistema. En casos extremos, el sistema puede simplemente matar el proceso de la aplicación sin llamar a la devolución de llamada onDestroy() final de la actividad, por lo que es importante que utilices onStop() para liberar recursos que podrían perder memoria.

Aunque el método onPause() se llama despues de onStop(), debe usar onStop() para realizar operaciones de apagado más grandes y más intensivas en la CPU, como escribir información en una base de datos.

Puedes echar un vistazo al ciclo de vida aquí:

Comment: Te pongo yo un enlace http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android/37-unidad-6-multimedia-y-ciclo-de-vida/158-ciclo-de-vida-de-una-actividad Aunque no se si es el que te quería poner @Manuel Robles ;)